# Am trying to enable some buttons after inputting login credentials but the my code is not working

Tags: c#

Below is my code, I am trying to enable the buttons after the user inputs correct credentials, the code runs fine without errors but buttons are not enabled. After the user inputs their credentials, the buttons are supposed to be enabled.

```
public partial class Login : Form
{

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //textBoxusername.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=HENRY\\SQL_2017;Initial Catalog=Hotel;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + textBoxusername.Text + "' AND password = '" + textBoxpassword.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.Hide();

            if (this.Owner != null)
            {
                (this.Owner as Home).buttonClients.Enabled = true;
                (this.Owner as Home).buttonRooms.Enabled = true;
                (this.Owner as Home).buttonReservations.Enabled = true;
                (this.Owner as Home).buttonRoomAttendants.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (textBoxusername.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Username To Login", "NO USERNAME!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (textBoxpassword.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Your Password To Login", "NO PASSWORD!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Correct Login Credentials", "INVALID LOGIN CREDENTIALS!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should be using a parameterized query instead. Reference [the sad tale of little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Did you step through your code with the debugger to make sure it's really taking the execution path you think it is?

Comment: i changed the methods/functions from private to public so they can be accessed by the login class

Comment: I don't understand how that's relevant to the question. Did that fix the problem? I thought you said the application already ran okay, just didn't behave as expected. But what you're describing sounds like it would have resulted in a compiler error.

Comment: If `Login` has a `.Owner`, then it was not the first form displayed.  Presumably, `Home` displays `Login`.  Display the `Login` form with `ShowDialog(this)` and capture the return value back in the `Home` form: `DialogResult result = frmLogin.ShowDialog(this);`  In the Login form, set `DialogResult` to OK only on a valid login.  You can check that result and enable the buttons directly in the `Home` form itself.

Comment: Not only is your query subject to an injection attack (thanks @itsme86) but you also should not be storing the password in the clear in a database table.  See [password storage cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) for some pointers

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the database side of the house, set `DialogResult` in form `Login` to "OK" when a successful login has occurred:

```
// ... in form Login ...
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // this.Hide(); not necessary
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // form is hidden for you, and execution returns to the `Home` form                
}
else
{
    // ... messages about failed login ...
}
```

Back in form `Home`, you'd do something like:

```
Login frmLogin = new Login();
if (frmLogin.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) // code stops here until `frmLogin` is dismissed
{
    this.buttonClients.Enabled = true;
    this.buttonRooms.Enabled = true;
    this.buttonReservations.Enabled = true;
    this.buttonRoomAttendants.Enabled = true;
}
else 
{
    // login failed...possibly do something else in here
}
```

Comment: The  `ShowDialog()` code (second block) is in the `Home` form, as that is what is displaying the `Login` form.  You didn't show that code, so you may need to change the variable name from "frmLogin"  to whatever your instance of `Login` is called.

Comment: Glad it helped. Be sure to upvote or accept at some point.